# How can I log in instagram using ruby with mechanize

Tags: ruby

How can I log in instagram using ruby with mechanize?

I tried but it seems that is being used javascript or something like that.

plese tell me how I can log in instagram using ruby with mechanize.

Comment: I did something similar to export bank statements from the website. https://github.com/sebastianzillessen/ynab/blob/master/lib/debit_dkb.rb. But it doesn't work with javascript. I think you could try it and use `capybara` in combination with `poltergeist` and `phantomJS`, this definitely supports Javascript execution.

Comment: A lot of sites make it intentionally difficult to script logins. A headless browser works better. Is there a reason you're not using the api?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible as the Instagram website is entirely written in React, a JavaScript UI framework, and the [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) library doesn't process JavaScript at all. The form doesn't exist in the DOM until React kicks in, so there's nothing for Mechanize to do.

Consider using [Watir](https://github.com/watir/watir), which uses Selenium Webdriver and can handle JavaScript just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login')
agent.page.forms[0]['username'] = 'username'
agent.page.forms[0]['password'] = 'password'
agent.page.forms[0].submit
```